# Python - Finding Index Location Function

Tags: python, string, character

What is the complexity of the following function??

```
def find_set(string, chars):
    schars = set(chars)
    for i, c in enumerate(string):
        if c in schars:
            return i
    return -1 

print(find_set("Happy birthday", "py"))
```

In this instance, a 1 is returned, since H is at index 1 of CHEERIO.

Is it possible to further optimize this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (worst case) time complexity is `O(len(string) * len(set))`.  Yes you can do better (at least from an algorithms perspective).

```
def find_set(string, chars):
    schars = set(chars)
    return next((i for i, c in enumerate(string) if c in schars), -1)
```

This should execute in `O(len(chars) + len(string))` (worst case).  Of course, when it comes to "optimization", usually you should forget what you think you know and profile.  Just because mine has better algorithmic complexity doesn't mean that it will perform better on *your* real world data.

Comment: @ITellMyselfSecrets -- If the generator yields no items, then `next` will raise `StopIteration` by default.  You can suppress this and tell `next` to return a particular value by supplying a second argument.  See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next).

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain the for loop? Im having a hard time deciphering it.

Comment: @user3624831 -- It's a generator expression.  First, I enumerate the string.  This yields 2-tuples of the form (index, character).  I unpack that tuple into `i, c`.  I look to see if `c` is in the set of characters `if c in schars` and if it is, the loop yields `i` (the index).  The builtin `next` function just picks off the first thing yielded (and doesn't bother with the rest) which gets returned.  If _nothing_ gets yielded, then `next` returns the "default" -- in this case `-1`

Comment: @user3624831 -- `next` gets a value from the generator expression.  If you don't call next, the generator expression never yields any values.

Comment: Why is it necessary to call next? Would this function (without next) also have a time complexity of O(len(string) * len(set))? def find_set(string, chars): schars = set(chars) for i, c in enumerate(string): if c in schars: return i return -1